# C# Access db complex stored procedure error

Tags: c#, ms-access, dataadapter

Looking for an hint on this strange problem.

I'm trying to retrieve data from a access (OleDb)  db into a c#/wpf DataTable. Now the funny thing is: a simple query works in access and is downloaded into the Datatable, just fine. A (slightly) more complex query works in Access but gives an error in c#.

Here's the code:

```
 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("myconn");
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
 OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

 conn.Open();

       //3 flavors          
       //string n = "QryTestComplex";        This gives an error in c#, works in access
       //string n = "SELECT * FROM CURSIST"; This works ( with cmd.CommandType =  
                                                                   etc, commented out)
       //string n = "QryTestSimple";         This works   ( SQL = same as above )

cmd = new OleDbCommand(n,conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                int t = 0;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                { t++; Console.WriteLine(t + dr[0].ToString()); }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", exc);
            }

            conn.Close();
```

The queries are:

QryTestSimple:

```
SELECT * FROM Cursist;
```

QryTestComplex:

```
SELECT 
    Module.Status, 
    ModuleData.Datum, 
    LeerActiviteit.Naam, 
    Module.Locatie, 
    Module.Onderwijskundige, 
    Module.Organisator, 
    Module.Coordinator, 
    Module.Stoplicht, 
    Module.ID, Cluster.Naam AS CNaam, 
    (
        SELECT '(dag' & count(M.ID) + 1 & ')'  
        FROM  
            Module AS M  
            INNER JOIN ModuleData AS MD 
                ON M.ID = MD.Module_ID 
        WHERE Module.ID = M.ID 
            AND MD.Datum <ModuleData.Datum  
        HAVING  
            (
                SELECT count(P.ID) 
                FROM 
                    Module AS P 
                    INNER JOIN 
                    ModuleData AS PD 
                        ON P.ID = PD.Module_ID  
                WHERE Module.ID= P.ID 
            ) >1 
    ) AS DagNummer
FROM 
    (
        LeerActiviteit 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            [Module] 
            LEFT JOIN 
            Cluster 
                ON Module.Onderdeel_Van_Cluster_ID = Cluster.ID
        ) 
            ON LeerActiviteit.ID = Module.LeerAct_ID
    ) 
    INNER JOIN 
    ModuleData 
        ON Module.ID = ModuleData.Module_ID
WHERE (((ModuleData.Datum)>Now()));
```

The Complex query works in access, but when debugging in C# I get:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed
>   with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

Breaks on `adapter.Fill(dt);`

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Arnold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

`cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

T'ain't no such thing in Access.  If you're reading a query as is, make it .Table.  If you're composing a select statement, make it .Text.

Comment: Actually, Access does support rather simple [stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845861%28v=office.14%29.aspx), although I've never had the occasion to use one myself.

Comment: Meredith, thanks for your fast reply. Unfortunatly CommandType.Text or .TableDirect gives the same error on the complex query. The simple query does work with commandtype.storedprocedure.

Comment: Thanks Gord, am I confusing Stored Procedures and Queries here? I thought I could run a select query with commandtype.storedprocedure. To naive? Still dont get it why the simple query works, then.

Comment: Solved ( kind of ): I removed the complex sub query (....AS DAGNUMMER) from the query, now it works. Looks like Access doesnt like to be told to execute subqueries, or C# doesnt know how to handle the result..... Beats me.